# Easiest way to fade to another sprite sheet position in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I'm working on a website that has multiple images on separate sprite sheets (like the two in [this link (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cahnF.jpg). I'm trying to fade the duller image into the brighter one and I've been using something like:

```
.display {
    background-image: url("../images/1.png");
    display: block;
    background-position: 0 -53px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 53px;
}
.display:hover {
    background-image: url("../images/1.png");
    display: block;
    background-position: 0 0px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 53px;
}
```

This works, but it just makes the image change instantly, where I would prefer some kind of a "fade in" or "glow" effect on hover. What would be the easiest way to achieve the result I want? I'm thinking it would be either jQuery or something in CSS3, but I haven't really had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS 3, you can do this way, setting the `opacity` and adding the `transformation`, there by you would need only one image! Check out this:

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Opera */
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Opera */
}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBeed/

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I can also combine all of our icons onto the same sheet now without having a big mess. :)

Answer (score 0):

place a div in the container with a hover class, then fade in the hover div. i've done this before... this will work for any browser, even ie7/ie8

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover"></div>
</div>

$(".container").hover(function(){
    $(".hover", this).fadeIn();
});

.container {
    position:relative;
}

.container.hover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
```